# disable the unselected rows in ui-grid angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I'm using `UI-grid` for AngularJS

I have array - when the length is 0 for example choosing 4 rows , I open a popup.
but I need to disable the other rows - that unselected and prevent from the user to select them until the length will be > 0.

How can I do that?

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37430198/5954939

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent Row selection on custom elements click in UI-GRID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429893/how-to-prevent-row-selection-on-custom-elements-click-in-ui-grid)